# Why CultureInfo with country only is a neutral culture?

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo

Maybe i don't understand what a neutral culture is, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.isneutralculture?view=net-7.0) is explicit:

> A neutral culture is a culture that is **associated with a language but
> not with a country** or region. It differs from a specific culture,
> which is a culture that is associated with both a language and a
> country or region. For example, fr is the name for the neutral French
> culture, while fr-FR is the name for the French culture in France.

So i'd exptect that this is a neutral culture and in fact it is:

```
var englishCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
Console.WriteLine(englishCulture.IsNeutralCulture); // True
```

But this is just the country without language, so it's not a neutral culture:

```
var greatBritainCulture = new CultureInfo("GB");
Console.WriteLine(greatBritainCulture.IsNeutralCulture); // True
```

But it's also a neutral culture. Why? The same applies to `US` for example.

Of course for en-GB it returns false as expected:

```
Console.WriteLine(new CultureInfo("en-GB").IsNeutralCulture); // False
```

Comment: There is no GB language so you get something back that is "totally"? neutral. That GB is a country is just coincidental but i think ignored here. You could have tried "XX" and you would get the same Culture back.

Comment: If its unknown you seem to get something back derived from local settings. For a "GB" culture i get german day names back.

Comment: @Ralf: you're right, didn't know that you can create a valid CultureInfo from two arbitrary letters. Why is that so? Maybe that's the better question then.

Comment: asking that myself :( The constructor docu talks about a CultureNotFoundException exception. But i only seem to get that one if i use something syntactical incorrect for a culture. Still trying to decipher the remarks.

Comment: @Ralf: You get the CultureNotFoundException for example if it has 1 or more than 3 characters(String.Empty is valid though) and if it contains digits. Does that make sense?

Comment: LOCALE_CUSTOM_UNSPECIFIED is 0x1000 ... What is `new CultureInfo("zz").LCID`  and `new CultureInfo("GB").LCID` ?

Comment: @Selvin it is `4096` for both as far as I can see.

Comment: Well ... so it's LOCALE_CUSTOM_UNSPECIFIED

Comment: [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0A4gDYD2ARgIbECWAXpcDaVANzrp4CcAFAESAeDcAg+3wCU7NADdKYbAHMwAU0YAhMDWCUaUAMIRiwCEuwBebFEUB3bHoNHFASSgAzUv0IqxE7jwXLgahpauvqGSvgAMjoOACLinEi8fqrqmtq2YYr4DgDOAHKKEMBg1Bn24tgA9JXYACqQihxoCbwW1mVKTq78dHRikdFxrEA)

Comment: @Selvin: But there is a switch in the int-constructor and if it's `LOCALE_CUSTOM_UNSPECIFIED` it will throw new CultureNotFoundException. Indeed: this throws:  `var gb = new CultureInfo("GB");
        var gb2 = new CultureInfo(gb.LCID);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter [_"Supplemental locales cannot be distinguished from one another by their locale identifiers, but can be distinguished by their locale names. "_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-custom-constants), there are bunch if cultures with this LCID, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @GuruStron Aren't we using ICU in a current framework and not NLS?

Comment: @Ralf we should AFAIK. But icu does not know such cultures, so this should be somehow connected.

Comment: `new CultureInfo("GB")` is handled as a custom culture, with `GB` being the language; `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` returns `gb` (the lowercased `GB`). With only a langauge, it is also seen as neutral. It's rather rare to use the constructor of a `CultureInfo`; to retrieve a culture you can use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(...)`.

Comment: @pfx CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo behaves the same as the constructor in this regard.

Comment: @Ralf, to prevent getting a custom culture, we need to pass `true` to the `predefinedOnly` argument `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("GB", true)`. Then it will throw that `CultureNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `new CultureInfo("GB")` is handled as a custom culture, with `GB` being the language.
The `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` returns `gb`, which is the lowercased `GB` value.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("GB");
Console.WriteLine(culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName); // gb
```

With only a language specified, the culture is considered to be neutral.

---

To avoid ending up with a custom culture when expecting a predefined, one you can retrieve a culture via [`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string name, bool predefinedOnly)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo)

When passing `true` as value for `predefinedOnly`, a `CultureNotFoundException` will be thrown for an undefined culture.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("GB", true);
```

Comment: The linked doc at least has remarks that the system will " try constructing a culture with data from other cultures or some constant values." if its not found in the default case (using the ctor or GetCulture with just a culture name) but presumably the best "why"  answer we can get.

Comment: @Ralf Agreed. That document could use some more details about that "from other cultures".